# EMGU library OPENCV problem with native memroy management - does really work with mono?

Tags: linux, opencv, wrapper, svm

we are working in a project involving the use of EMGU and in particoular the SVM functions of OpenCV and we have a problem using Mono on a Ubuntu platform and we don't have this problem on windows. The problem appears when we call the Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.Train method. All the parameters are correct and we canno't debug the wrapped code...

We have tried to increase the Shared Memory and other tricks but it doesn't work. 
Do you have any idea?
Thank you
Angelo

```
Unhandled Exception: Emgu.CV.CvException: OpenCV: requested size is negative or too big
  at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler (Int32 status, System.String funcName, System.String errMsg, System.String fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData) [0x00000] 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Emgu.CV.CvInvoke:CvErrorHandler (int,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,intptr)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Emgu.CV.ML.MlInvoke:CvSVMTrain (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,Emgu.CV.ML.Structure.MCvSVMParams)
  at Emgu.CV.ML.SVM.Train (Emgu.CV.Matrix`1 trainData, Emgu.CV.Matrix`1 responses, Emgu.CV.Matrix`1 varIdx, Emgu.CV.Matrix`1 sampleIdx, Emgu.CV.ML.SVMParams parameters) [0x00000] 
  at Segmentation.ImageFeatures.LeafHog.TrainModel (IDictionary`2 dicInOutImage) [0x00000] 
  at Segmentation.ImageSegmentators.Composite.TrainModel (IDictionary`2 dicInOutImage) [0x00000] 
  at Segmentation.ImageSegmentators.CompositionMlpRprop.TrainModel (IDictionary`2 dicInOutImage) [0x00000] 
  at Segmentation.GeneticConfig.ChromoCreator.GetASegmentation (IConfigChromosome configChromosome, IDictionary`2 dicInOutImageTrain) [0x00000] 
  at Segmentation.GeneticConfig.ConfigChromoProvider.AddChromosomeIfNew (IConfigChromosome chromo) [0x00000] 
  at Segmentation.GeneticConfig.ConfigChromosome.Generate () [0x00000] 
  at Segmentation.GeneticConfig.ConfigChromosome..ctor (Int32 chromoLength, IConfigChromoProvider cProvider) [0x00000] 
  at Segmentation.GeneticConfig.ConfigChromosome.CreateNew () [0x00000] 
  at AForge.Genetic.Population..ctor (Int32 size, IChromosome ancestor, IFitnessFunction fitnessFunction, ISelectionMethod selectionMethod) [0x00000] 
  at SegmentationCLI.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]
```